# How can I subtract 2 dates in Mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have 2 dates; sales_date (When the service was sold) and the cancellation_date (When the service was cancelled). I want to calculate the tenure by Month doing a subtraction between cancellation_date - sales_date.

This is the code that I am currently doing:

```
router.get('/subtract_date', auth, async (req, res) => {
try {
    const model_CancellationKPI = await CancellationKPI.aggregate([ 
        { "$project" : { "difference" : { "$subtract" : ["$cancellation_date", "$sales_date"] } } }
    ])

    res.json(model_CancellationKPI);


} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
});
```

And the JSON output is:

```
  {
    "_id": "5d30c48e5fbf3c0507250bb5",
    "difference": 31536000000
}
```

I have this JSON: How can I output a JSON displaying the tenure in month (cancellation_date - sales_date) by client_name?

[image]

Comment: is this an array?  ["$cancellation_date", "$sales_date"]? if not, use  {"$cancellation_date", "$sales_date"}

Answer (score 1):

```
await CancellationKPI.aggregate([ 
    { "$project" : { "difference" : { "$subtract" : ["$cancellation_date", "$sales_date"] } ,  $add: [
      new Date(0),
      "$difference"
    ] }}
]);
```

Your query of date difference is working alright , it should give the result in milliseconds all it needs to be converted back to date , checkout [toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/#example) aggregation. You can check [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z6hNUnI1IhU) for the result of above query

Comment: I received the following error message: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Comment: I might have misplaced the closing braces ,please check now edited the answer @ManfredTijerino

Comment: I received this error message now: Error parsing date string 'difference'; 0: passing a time zone identifier as part of the string is not allowed 'd'; 6: Double timezone specification 'e'